# Resizing a div when resizing page

Tags: jquery, overlay, resize

I am using jquery to place an overlay over a div while I am waiting for my server to return to my a json table that I automatically over to (there are two tabs, when you do an ajax post on one, a table is created using JSON data from the server response).

That seems to be working just fine.
However, when I resize my screen, the overlay stays the same size.
That is no good.

That overlay div needs to resize when someone shrinks or expands the window.
I have tried a couple of different things, including posting here to stack overflow.

Also, I tried to attach the size of my div overlay to a `$(window).resize` function inside of my overlay function.

Basically setting the `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` css attributes to the `div.outerWidth()`, `outerHeight()`, `left`, `top` properties.

That doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

**CODE for what I Do**

```
        $('<div id="overlay">').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        opacity: 0.2,
        top : $div.offset().top,
        left : $div.offset().left,
        width : $div.offset().width,
        height : $div.outerHeight(),
        background: 'blue url(<%=Url.Content("~/images/ajax-loader.gif")%>) no-repeat center'
    }).hide().appendTo('body');
```

As you can see, I pretty much do all of my css work inside of a javascript function.  I guess I could do all of css stuff in a style sheet like you guys suggest and just append and hide my div to the DOM. I will give it a try.

Comment: For some reason, My overlay isn't even showing up at all... Very frustrating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Answers fellow stack Overflow enthusiasts.   I recently solved the problem by simply attaching the overlay to the correct div instead of trying to overlay it over that div and then calculate the size...  Here is what I did.  There is a subtle change that i will point out.

```
function MRNSearchInternals()
{
    //debugger;
    var form = $("#MRNSearch");
    $div = $("#TabView1");
    var srlzdform = form.serialize();
    var PopID = <% =PopID %>;
    var options = [];
    var $url = $("#target").attr("action");
    $('<div id="overlay">').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        opacity: 0.2,
        top : $div.offset().top,
        left : $div.offset().left,
        width : $div.outerWidth(),
        height : $div.outerHeight(),
        background: 'grey url(<%=Url.Content("~/images/ajax-loader.gif")%>) no-repeat center'
    }).hide().appendTo($div);    

    $("#overlay").fadeIn();
    $.post('<%:Url.Action("SearchByMRN", "PatientACO")%>', srlzdform, function (data) 
    {                   
        DisplayDemographicSearch(data);
        $("#overlay").fadeOut('slow', function () {
             $("#overlay").remove();
        });
    });
}
```

Previously, I attached the overlay div to 'body'.  Now I attach it to the div that I previously grabbed...  $div... I have know idea why that worked, but the overlay now grows and shrinks with the window size.  Any insight into that guys?  It would be great to not only have solved this problem, but I would like to learn why the problem was solved as well so I can make a more informed decision next time.  Thanks for all of your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Use `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` on the overlay div.

Width is not a problem, will work as it is.
Height is slightly more tricky, for it to work you need to have the parent of the overlay div, to have a known width. So assuming the overlay div is a direct child of `body` the following will be required:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and then on the overlay div.

---

Another possibility is to set the following on the div:

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**[Here's an Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vUzv7/)**

Note that `position: fixed` does not work well with mobile devices.

Comment: position: fixed doesnt work on iPad and other mobile devices ;)

Comment: The problem is not apple, but the general difficulty to implement the `fixed` attribute on mobile devices. Often, menus use this feature and they would block the whole screen. Interesting article: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/12/the_fifth_posit.html

Comment: It is the designer's responsibility to not kill the mobile device with crap. I still think position: fixed should be enabled on mobile. If a site breaks, it's not designed correctly (most mobile browsers support media queries, get creative!)

Answer (score 1):

How about a pure HTML/CSS solution?

```
<div id="overlay"></div>

<style type="text/css">
  #overlay {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;

      background: #000000;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
</style>
```

(The `background` property is specified twice for devices with and without css3 support; only demonstration.)

Answer (score 1):

for overlay:
put it in the root of DOM, where you dont use overflow:hidden, for example after body tag

```
body: position: relative
overlay: position: absolute, width: 100%, top:0, left: 0
```

and script for height:

```
$('overlay-selector').height($(document).height())
```

100% height with CSS means $(window).height(), so you need to use script.